# How to see in iPhone app that Google Document has changed?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, gdata-api, multi-user

I'm new in iPhone apps and GData API. 
I want to use Google Documents like a data storage for my multi-user application, there is a need to control access rights to data:

If the first user takes data, then he can read & write it, all others users will be able only to read. But when first user finishes his work with data and quits application, i want the second user to get rights for writing.

Help me pls finding the way to solve this.

My idea is like this: i need to have two files, "ApplicationData" file, where my data will be stored, and "DataInfo" file, where names of users who work with data will be stored in right sequence. When first user quits, he deletes the first line with his name in "DataInfo". And all others users, who has only read access, have to download "DataInfo" every minute (for example) and check, if the situation changed. But i'm very doubt, its a good way to solve my problem. I dont think, thas its good for an amount of users to download same file so often.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Locking out other users probably will not work reliably, as an app will almost certainly neglect to "unlock" the document when it has been quit unexpectedly.

So long as uploaded updates to Google Docs have the proper ETag attribute (gd:etag) in the document entry, then a client app attempting to update a document will receive an error indicating the document on the server has changed. The client app must then download the version from the server and reconcile the differences, if any.

If different users are attempting to edit the same document, you will likely need to set appropriate access-control list entries for the document so the document is accessible to all users.

While Google Docs is intended for simultaneous, real-time collaboration among multiple users, the Docs API is not. In circumstances where multiple users are actively trying to work with the same document, you will probably need to create your own server to have a reliable solution.